# How to prevent chocolate from melting?

Tags: chocolate

It is tough to store chocolates during summer season. Is there any way to prevent chocolate from melting ?

Comment: Do you have air conditioning? Refrigerator? Freezer? Any way at all to chill things?

Answer (score 2):

I store mine in the freezer. It keeps it hard and thaws without an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Fridge or freezer are both good places to keep your chocolate so it doesn't get melty. If those aren't an option for some reason, then try finding a cool, dark place that won't get too much hotter during the day. A couple ideas:

1) A cellar. Cellars often stay 10-15 degrees cooler than the house they're attached too.

2) Cupboards - if choosing this option, pick a cupboard that has a tight fitting door, is somewhat large (so there's more air in there to stay cool) and that is close to the floor. All of these will help it stay cooler during the day.

3) Pack in an insulator - putting it in a cooler or surrounding it with styrofoam packing, for example. Alternately, you could try to find another insulating material/food already in your kitchen (maybe packing it in rice or flour might work? You might just end up with chocolate-y rice/flour).

Really, the fridge is your best bet if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

For optimal chocolate storage, you shouldn't really store it in the freezer or the fridge. Chocolate is sensitive to temperature and the taste does change if it's cooled too far. Not to mention condensation usually occurs on the chocolate afterwards, and water and chocolate are generally non-mixy things.

But then again, you might not care too much about that, and I suppose it depends on what you're using the chocolate for (baking, eating, decorating, etc.) as to whether it would matter all that much.

Personally, I would suggest a microwave. It can act as an insulator of sorts. You could also use it to keep things warm too, sort of like a vacuum flask. Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Never, ever keep chocolate in a pocket. Avoid keeping chocolate in a backpack. If you have air conditioning, you should be fine leaving it out. If you don't have air conditioning, freeze your chocolate and then defrost it an hour before consuming.

Answer (score -3):

You will need an isolated box, that you keep cool. This can be done by adding ready made ice, or by a closed-circuit pump system, that removes hotter gas molecules before feeding them back in the system, so inside of the box is it colder, and outside, where the pump is, it is hotter.

Comment: In laymen terms: use a fridge, freezer, or cooler with ice.

Comment: Never been that good with laymens' terms answering complicated questions. Thank you.

Comment: I have refrigerator but iam a chocolate manufacturer in india..so the weather is too hot in summers so even its tough to make a chocolate in sunny days.That is the reason people stop making chocolates in summers here.Is there any way to run business smoothly without any weather hassles?